# android: why do we need Runnables in JobIntentService?

Tags: java, android

I am playing with `JobIntentService`, and the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) have this example:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
    ...
    toast("Executing");
    ...
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    toast("All work complete");
}

final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// Helper for showing tests
void toast(final CharSequence text) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(JsInvokerJobService.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I am new to Android, and I don't understand why they wrap `Toast.makeText` in a `Runnable` and don't use it directly in the `onHandleWork` and `onDestroy` methods. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) for Runnable don't really help. Is this specific to `JobIntentService` or not? What stuff should go into the `onHandleWork` method and what should be offloaded to a `Runnable` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to Android, and I don't understand why they wrap
> Toast.makeText in a Runnable

It is because `JobIntentService` runs on Background thread and the Toast can't be shown from it. The handler will post in the runloop queue of the ui thread your runnable and it will get executed on it